# Warnings encountered while simulating erratic

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.I am using ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.  While I was running erratic on gazebo, using

```
 roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch
```

I encountered the following warnings.

```
[ WARN] [1354625870.495205787, 49.740000000]: Message from  
[/base_laser_self_filter] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_footprint].  
Resolved locally to [/base_footprint].  This is will likely not work in 
multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1354625870.495682174, 49.740000000]: Message from 
[/base_laser_self_filter] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_footprint]. 
Resolved locally to [/base_footprint].  This is will likely not work in 
multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1354625910.922358012, 65.418000000]: The /base_scan/marking observation 
buffer has not been updated for 0.24 seconds, and it should be updated every 
0.20 seconds.
[ WARN] [1354625988.636103668, 91.693000000]: The /base_scan/marking observation 
buffer has not been updated for 0.21 seconds, and it should be updated every 
0.20 seconds.
[ WARN] [1354625993.083708417, 93.493000000]: The /base_scan/marking observation 
buffer has not been updated for 0.20 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 
seconds.
[ WARN] [1354625996.023810230, 94.695000000]: The /base_scan/marking observation 
buffer has not been updated for 0.20 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 
seconds.
```

My question is how should I get rid of the warning for observation buffer. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/410/warnings-encountered-while-simulating-erratic/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanker Keshavdas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/118/shanker-keshavdas/) on 2012-12-14**:
Are you running link:[this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/TeleopErraticSimulation). I do not even get a robot spawned using the direct instructions. Did you change the robot description from urdf to sdf format?

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-19**:
Hi Shanker. No i did not change the robot description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suspect that you don't have enough CPU cycles and that as a result some part of the system is running slower than expected.  Off-hand, I'm not sure whether it would be Gazebo itself (including plugins) or one of the ROS nodes.

In any case, have a look at your system load (e.g., with `top`).  If your system is very busy, try having Gazebo run slower: lower `<update_rate>` in the `.world` file that you're using.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2013-01-19**:
Thanks gerkey, i will try that. Looking back, I did realised that my PC will lag sometime when I run simulation.